# NGINX 404 not found but file exists

Tags: linux, nginx, server, host

I want to call the index.html from the folder /var/www/fileUpload/html. The index.html file exists in that folder.

The / router works. the uploadFiles route as well. But when I open the upload route I get a 404 error.

```
    server{
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        root /var/www/kioskJPE/html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /upload {
        root /var/www/fileUpload/html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /uploadFiles {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be `alias /var/www/fileUpload/html;` otherwise Nginx is looking for the file in `/var/www/fileUpload/html/upload/index.html`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location /upload {
    alias /var/www/fileUpload/html;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much!